# Is it possible to use a django viewset with two serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model for `Articles` which has a lot of fields. When someone fetches a specific article by `id` I want to send almost all of the fields back to the client.

However, when the articles list is generated I don't want to send all of the articles with all of that data, but rather limit each article to a few important listing fields, and forgo long fields like `content` etc..

Can I achieve these with an elegant tweak to the the `django_restframework.viewsets` module, or should I just build the api methods myself using `django_restframwork.generics` instead?

example:

```py
# articles/api/urls.py #
# -------------------- #

from articles.api.views import ArticlesViewSet
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ArticlesViewSet, basename='articles')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

```py
# articles/api/views.py #
# --------------------- #
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from ..models import Article
from .serializers import ArticleSerializerFull, ArticleSerializerShort


class ArticlesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # Perhaps some conditional code here?
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializerFull
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_serializer_class()` method in DRF to solve the problem...

## serializers.py

```
class ArticleFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('__all__')

class ArticleShortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('field1', 'field2' ... 'fieldn')
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class ArticleViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializerFull
    queryset = Article.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            serializer = ArticleShortSerializer
        else:
            serializer = ArticleFullSerializer
        return serializer
```

Answer (score 0):

**i believe you can achieve this  by using generics views [check_here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#concrete-view-classes) **

```
class ArticleFullSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('__all__')

class ArticleShortSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('field1', 'field2'..... 'fieldn')
```

**and in your views**

```
class ArticleListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleShortSerializer

class ArticleDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
   permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleFullSerializer
     lookup_field = 'pk'



  ****and in urls for details****

path('detail/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
```